# How can I access a variable in another function in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, self

I have this code, actually, I'm trying ***self***  because I'm not familiar with it:

```py
import tkinter

class AvakinLife:
    def __init__(self):
        self.targetFile = 'D:\AVAKIN_PROJECT\SOFTWARE\order.txt'
        self.cursor = ["arrow", "circle", "clock", "cross", "dotbox", "pirate"]
        self.background = 'black'
        self.fg = '#00ff00'
        self.font = 'bold'
        self.mod = 'w+'
        self.GUI = tkinter.Tk()
        self.GUI.title('Avakin Life Resources Generator')
        self.GUI.geometry('350x200')
        self.GUI.configure(background='black', cursor=self.cursor[5])

    def post(self):
        f = open(self.targetFile, self.mod)
        with f as writer:
            # Here is my problem
            writer.write("email> " + email_Entry.get() + '\r')
        writer.close()

    def create_GUI(self):
        emailLabel = tkinter.Label(master=self.GUI, text='Account e-mail: ', background=self.background, fg=self.fg)
        emailLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=4)
        email_Entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self.GUI, background=self.background, fg=self.fg, font=self.font)
        email_Entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        send = tkinter.Button(master=self.GUI, text='Send', background=self.background, fg=self.fg, font=self.font,width=10, command=AL.post)
        send.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=8)

        self.GUI.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AL = AvakinLife()
    AL.create_GUI()
```

The error is:

```
writer.write("email> " + email_Entry.get.get() + '\r')
NameError: name 'email_Entry' is not defined
```

And, I don't know what the problem is. I searched over the internet, and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: ***"I'm trying self"***: Don't try, use it. Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: A local variable declared within a function cannot be accessed outside. If you want to use variables across functions in a class, define them as instance variable. Read this page, it will be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: In the method post(self) you use email_Entry, but it is not defined here. You define it in create_gui, if you want to pass this object to the post method, you need to add it to the class namespace. So just add and use self.email_Entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable that you defined in the create_GUI() method called email_entry, is a local variable.
Therefore, you will not be able to utilize the variable outside that method.
To fix this, you just have to set that local variable as a class attribute.
The self keyword does just that.
by doing:

```
    self.email_Entry = tkinter.Entry(master=self.GUI, background=self.background, fg=self.fg, font=self.font)
```

email_Entry is now a class property and thus, it can be called from other methods as well.
With that said, your post() method will become:

```
    def post(self):
        f = open(self.targetFile, self.mod)
        with f as writer:
            writer.write("email> " + self.email_Entry.get() + '\r')
        writer.close()
```